# How does one allow the user to input feet and inches with an apostrophe inbetween?

Tags: c++

For example if we have something like this in the code

`int height;`

`cin >> height;`

user inputs

`5'9`

How would I go about making that work?

It would be easy enough to have

`cin >> feet;`

`cin >> inches;`

`cout << feet << "'" << inches << "\n\n";`

and put it together but it's just not that neat or practical of a program for the end user.

How would I be able to make it so the user can type `5'9` with the apostrophe, and still have the code understand it and use it?

Essentially what I would need it to understand is that the `5` represents 12*5 (12 inches in a foot) + the 9.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can read in two variables in succession and then use them to compute a new variable (e.g. `int height = 12 * feet + inches;`), or you could write your own type that has an overloaded `operator>>` and make `height` an object of that type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way

```
int feet, inches;
char apos;

cin >> feet >> apos >> inches;
```

The `apos` variable is there to read the `'`. This code has no error checking, you can add that if you like (including checking that `apos` really is an apostrophe).

```
if ((cin >> feet >> apos >> inches) && apos == '\'')
{
     // do something with feet and inches
     ...
}
else
{
     // some kind of error handling
     ...
}
```

Comment: Such a simple solution. I could make a switch statement with this kind of idea to support multiple ways the end user might type in their height.

Additionally I just learnt thanks to you that you can put in a whole cin statement inside an if condition.

Thank you!

Comment: I have a question if I may. What does the `== '\''` mean in the `if` statement? Should it not simply be `== '`? Thanks

Comment: In C++ you use a pair of `'` to denote a character literal. So `'A'` is the letter A for instance. Unfortunately when the character literal you wish to use is a single quote, you can't say `'''` because of the special meaning of `'`. So you have to *escape* the `'` character with a backslash, giving `'\''`.